# bash or zsh: how to pass multiple inputs to interactive piped parameters?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, zsh

I have 3 different files that I want to compare

words_freq
words_freq_deduped
words_freq_alpha

For each file, I run a command like so, which I iterate on constantly to compare the results.

For example, I would do this:

```
$ cat words_freq | grep -v '[soe]'
$ cat words_freq_deduped | grep -v '[soe]'
$ cat words_freq_alpha | grep -v '[soe]'
```

and then review the results, and then do it again, with an additional filter

```
$ cat words_freq | grep -v '[soe]' | grep a | grep r | head -n20
a

$ cat words_freq_deduped | grep -v '[soe]' | grep a | grep r | head -n20
b

$ cat words_freq_alpha | grep -v '[soe]' | grep a | grep r | head -n20
c
```

This continues on until I've analyzed my data.

I would like to write a script that could take the piped portions, and pass it to each of these files, as I iterate on the grep/head portions of the command.

e.g. The following would dump the results of running the 3 commands above AND also compare the 3 results, and dump additional calculations on them

```
$ myScript | grep -v '[soe]' | grep a | grep r | head -n20
the letters were in all 3 runs, and it took 5 seconds
a
b
c
```

How can I do this using bash/python or zsh for the `myScript` part?

**EDIT: After asking the question, it occurred to me that I could use `eval` to do it, like so**, which [I've added as an answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71093233/26510)

The following approach allows me to process multiple files by using `eval`, which I know is frowned upon - any other suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
$ myScript "grep -v '[soe]' | grep a | grep r | head -n20"
```

#### myScript

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function doIt(){
  FILE=$1
  CMD="cat $1 | $2"
  echo processing file "$FILE"
  eval "$CMD"
  echo
}

doIt words_freq "$@" 
doIt words_freq_deduped "$@" 
doIt words_freq_alpha "$@"
```

Comment: The common pipeline should probably be the function: `doIt () { grep -v '[soe]' | ...; }`. The call the function with each file as input: `for f in words_freq_*; do doIt < "$f"; done`. If you want to do additional calculations on the result, pipe the output of the loop to another command/function.

Comment: You have a high rep and have been on the site for 13 years so I'm very surprised I have to say this but - please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates your problem and we can copy/paste to test with. See [ask]. Right now it reads like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/361691) as you seem to be asking for help implementing a specific solution you think you need to a problem rather than asking for help to solve a problem.

Comment: @EdMorton - sometimes you're not sure how to do something at all, so sometimes the solution isn't obvious and you're not sure which way to go - so I intentionally left the "what the script does" part of this question out - so it wouldn't be implied "please code this for me" It only occurred to me after the fact to use `eval`, which works, but is not safe. I will edit the question and put that approach in as well

Comment: Is `grep -v '[soe]' | grep a | grep r | head -n20` a fixed pipeline of commands and you just want to know how to run that set of commands against a fixed set of 3 files or are you asking how to write a script that can run any series of commands passed as an argument on a fixed set of 3 files or do you want to know how to write a command that given an argument can run either `grep -v '[soe]'` or `grep -v '[soe]' | grep a | grep r | head -n20` or both, or something else? A [mcve] we could test with would help a lot.

Comment: Also [edit] your question to show how you would want to call `myScript` at the end of your question. It's intended to be a different script from the script `myScript` used earlier in your question, right?

Comment: How I would call `myScript` is included already at the beginning of the question, so I didn't include an example there. And `myScript` is the same script in both places. The question is still stated as clearly as I think it can be, basically "how to pass multiple inputs to interactive piped parameters?" Maybe I should've said "files" instead, perhaps, or "how to pass multiple files to the same interactive piped parameters?". But on further review, I see the myScript I added at the end is different than the original question, so I will add something there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach allows me to process multiple files by using `eval`, which I know is frowned upon - any other suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
$ myScript "grep -v '[soe]' | grep a | grep r | head -n20"
```

#### myScript

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function doIt(){
  FILE=$1
  CMD="cat $1 | $2"
  echo processing file "$FILE"
  eval "$CMD"
  echo
}

doIt words_freq "$@" 
doIt words_freq_deduped "$@" 
doIt words_freq_alpha "$@"
```

Comment: You should include that script in your question rather than post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid your shell from running pipes itself, so using it like that isn't very practical - you'd need to either quote everything and then eval it, which would make it hard to pass arguments with spaces, or quote every pipe, which you can then eval, making it so you have to quote every pipe. But yeah, these solutions are kinda hacky.

I'd suggest doing one of these two:

1. Keep your editor open, and put whatever you want to run inside the doIt function itself before you run it. Then run it in your shell without any arguments:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doIt() {
  # grep -v '[soe]' < "$1"
  grep -v '[soe]' < "$1" | grep a | grep r | head -n20
}

doIt words_freq
doIt words_freq_deduped
doIt words_freq_alpha
```

Or, you could always use a "for" in your shell, which you can use Ctrl+r to find in your history when you want to use:

```sh
$ for f in words_freq*; do grep -v '[soe]' < "$f" | grep a | grep r | head -n20; done
```

But if you really want your approach, I tried to make it accept spaces, but it ended up being even hackier:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doIt() {
  local FILE=$1
  shift
  echo processing file "$FILE"
  local args=()

  for n in $(seq 1 $#); do
    arg=$1
    shift
    if [[ $arg == '|' ]]; then
      args+=('|')
    else
      args+=("\"$arg\"")
    fi
  done
  eval "cat '$FILE' | ${args[@]}"
}

doIt words_freq "$@" 
doIt words_freq_deduped "$@" 
doIt words_freq_alpha "$@"
```

With this version you can use it like this:

```
$ ./myScript grep "a a" "|" head -n1
```

Notice that it need you to quote the `|`, and that it now handles arguments with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understood problem correctly.

I understood you want to write a script without pipes, by including the filtering logic into the script.
And feeding the filtering patterns as arguments.

Here is a `gawk` script (standard Linux `awk`).

With one sweep on 3 input files, without piping.

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {
  RS="!@!@!@!@!@!@!@"; 
  # set record separator to something unlikely matched, causing each file to be read entirely as a single record
}
$0 !~ excludeRegEx      # if file does not match excludeRegEx
&& $0 ~ includeRegEx1   # and match includeRegEx1
&& $0 ~ includeRegEx2 { # and match includeRegEx2
  system "head -n20 "FILENAME; # call shell command "head -n20 " on current filename
}
```

#### Running script.awk

```
   awk -v excludeRegEx='[soe]' \
       -v includeRegEx1='a' \
       -v includeRegEx2='r' \
       -f script.awk words_freq words_freq_deduped words_freq_alpha
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - but I do want to use pipes is the thing, and I want to run it against 3 files, and then have it do some calculations on those 3 files... I like iterating on the cmd line, like it's a REPL - I run a command, think it needs more filtering or something, then I run it again. I came up [with a way to do what I want by using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71093233/26510) - not great, but works close enough!